# How to get the Stanley Parable Commitment Achievement

Tags: achievements, the-stanley-parable

I already did the other 9 achievements and this one is bugging me. I've read that you need to have game open during the duration of a Tuesday, but I was wondering if there is a easy way to do it, since the game is so tricky.

Comment: That's probably the way to do it. The Stanley Parable is crazy at times, that seems on par with what I could expect as an achievement.

Comment: I'm surprised you managed to get the 5-year achievement, since the game has barely been out for more than 2.

Comment: @Zibbobz the 5 year achievement is pretty easy, you can do it by starting the game, exit, change the system clock 5 years in the future and start the game again.

Comment: Am I the only one that finds achievements like this ridiculous? 99% of people will cheat to get this achievement, which completely defeats the purpose (bragging rights) of having it to begin with. It's almost more of a bragging right to *not* have this achievement.

Comment: You must not be aware of the game, one of the achievements the only way to win is to cheat, the game itself only unlocks some endings after you cheat. Also some of the achievements can be done more easily with minor things and restarts trough the game, therefore I have asked

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Another option:**

In order to get this achievement you just need to:

1. Set your computer time to 11:58pm on a Monday.
2. Launch the game.
3. I'm not sure about starting to play, but I did.
4. Then you should set your computer to go into hibernation mode.
5. Turn off and then turn on the computer.
6. But don't boot into the system, go into the BIOS.
7. Change the system time to about 11:57pm on Tuesday.
8. Save, exit and boot into the system.
9. Play a game a bit and enjoy getting an achievement!

FYI, you can see I have gotten this achievement [here](http://steamcommunity.com/id/mrdude42/stats/221910).

Comment: I tried this, but I can't go to the BIOS menu in Windows 10, or at least I don't know how.

Comment: Are you running windows? If so, right when your computer starts it should say some where on the screen to hold a certain button (sometimes its the delete button or one of the F1-F12 buttons) to open the bios. You can see an example here: http://goo.gl/iDuydU

Comment: The BIOS menu is independent from your OS. You can enter BIOS before the OS boots. It's dependant on your motherboard manufacturer how to enter the BIOS. Usually it's one of the F1-F12 buttons.

Comment: What I was getting at was whether he is running a Mac or PC. If it's a mac then there's no BIOS menu.

Comment: I'm running a PC with Windows 10, the thing is, that screen don't appear anymore, don't know if there is an option to toggle it or so.

Comment: Unfortunately, sometimes Win10 loads too quickly or skips the Post screen that usually tells you what button to press. You may have to try starting the computer and keep pressing F-12 and see if it goes into BIOS. If not, then start over and keep pressing F-11 and keep going until you figure out which button makes it go into the BIOS. Also remember to try DELETE button if F1-F12 don't work. Like @LeonvanNoord said, the BIOS is dependent on your motherboard so another option would be to look up the manual for your particular motherboard online and it will tell you how to access the BIOS.

Comment: Not sure if this applies to other manufacturers, but on my HP laptop I've been able to access the BIOS menu after hibernating by turning the laptop on and repeatedly pressing Esc to access the Startup Menu. From there, the option appeared to press F10 and go into the BIOS menu and change the system time through there. Doing so has granted me the achievement.

Answer (score 13):

I've tried this myself, and when they say you have to play the game for the entire duration of a Tuesday, they mean the **entire** duration, as in a full 24-hour period.

The most reliable way to do this would be to try keeping the game open from 11:59 PM on Monday, to 12:01 AM on Wednesday (times are based on your own system and not on the time at Valve). Also, you should turn off any sleep function on your computer that would shut down the game.

Comment: It's definitely local time, I did this achievement in the CET zone from Monday 11:50pm to 00:20am on Wednesday or so.

Comment: On a Mac system, you can type `caffeinate` into the terminal and it will prevent the computer from going to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

I just unlocked this achievement in "The Stanley Parable: Ultra Deluxe", and I've made kind of an interesting observation. Keep in mind that since this is technically a different game, this answer may not apply. They're both The Stanley Parable, and they both have this (seemingly) exact same achievement, so chances are it works exactly the same way, but it's also possible that this is just a change that was made for the new version.

So the thing is, when I say I just unlocked it, that's not entirely true. Rather, I just *realized* I've unlocked it. I had left the game running for the entire Tuesday, and towards midnight I tabbed back into it so I could witness the achievement pop up. But that didn't happen. Slightly worried something didn't work, I opened the Steam overlay, only to notice I do in fact already have the achievement, except that it had unlocked hours earlier, at around 2pm.

My theory for why this happened: I had actually already attempted this achievement a week earlier, but it failed, most likely because my device went to sleep after some time of inactivity, and I didn't realize that would invalidate the achievement. I only woke it back up around noon, and I think I've left it on consistently for the rest of the day after that.

So *it looks like* when they say "the entire duration of a Tuesday", they don't require you to do it all in one sitting, at least not in the Ultra Deluxe version. Apparently, it's enough to keep the game running from 2pm to midnight on one Tuesday, and then from midnight to 2pm on another Tuesday, because when combined, every moment of a Tuesday has been accounted for.